# Do Francophone children have a hard time with gender?

Tags: genre, linguistique

Would it be typical for a young Francophone child to make a mistake such as the following?

> Voilà mon chanson.

To what extent is memorizing words' gender something that native Francophone children struggle with, versus coming naturally as native speakers?

**EDIT**

Based on answers and comments I would like to contextualize. My 4-year old son has attended a French-immersion school since his second birthday and has heard fluent French at home since birth. I was startled when we were singing *Je danse le boogie-woogie* and he got *chanson* wrong.

Comment: This question is not specific to the French language but can be asked about any language with gender associated nouns. German, Spanish, Italian, etc. I'm not sure it belongs to linguistics.se either, maybe cognitivescience.se ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about French language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

French children are immersed in french language from their very first day. They listen to fairy tales that their parents read at night before sleeping, they watch TV, they ear adults speaking.

They always ear *ma/ta/sa/la/une chanson*, and never *mon/ton/son/le/un chanson*. They have no reason to associate *chanson* with incorrect gender.

If, like french children, you spend three or four years in a french-only environment, I bet that you won't struggle with gender anymore.

Comment: Oui, enfin Jane Birkin se plante encore régulièrement.

Comment: @Édouard - Ça fait partie de son personnage. Jodie Foster se plante beaucoup moins.

Comment: My personal and professional experience contradict this. Saying that French children are immersed in French language from their very fist day is a fallacy. France is a multicultural country and French is not the mother tongue of all those born in France and of French nationality. Thinking that "French children are immersed in French language from their very first day... listen to fairy tales that their parents read ..." **is** a fairy tale that concerns a minority of people, this is the same in lots of countries, nothing special to French or to the French.

Comment: @Laure - Do you mean that children that are not immersed still get genders correctly?

Comment: Some can do, yes. It is not only a question of being immersed, language acquisition is a complex question, part neurobiological, part social, part motivation.  Cognitivescience.se  might have a more scientific approach than fr.se

Answer (score 2):

My personal (and not researched) impression was that, for most common words, it comes naturally. Some rarer words (*tentacule*, e.g.) are an issue for children and adults alike.

One possible exception would be words which begins with a vowel, for which most  determiners are written (and often pronounced) the same whatever the gender. In that case, kids might get them wrong for longer.

Comment: Many words that start with a vowel are notorious for causing trouble to adults too, especially if their ending is not strongly associated with a gender (and sometimes even though it is): *aéroport*, *autobus*, *asphalte* and *escalier* come to mind.

Comment: There are even words which have switched gender.

Comment: @Circeus: Entirely agree with Circeus, one of the most common mistake in genders (from French people, whose mother tongue is French, I specify) is saying *une* ascenseur, and that is not a rare word.

Comment: @Laure Hell, I'm a **copyeditor** and I need to check the gender of *asphalte* every freakin' time!

Comment: @Circeus: et tu es francophone, si ma mémoire est bonne ! Et ça ne touche pas que la francophonie, les germanophones éprouvent parfois les mêmes problèmes pour retenir le genre de certians noms, il n'y a pas de raison pour que le problème ne touche pas toutes les langues qui ont des noms sexués. Et ça n'empêche pas les gens de se comprendre.